# Wrong result with SQL Server PreparedStatement in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, jakarta-ee, prepared-statement

I have query:

```
select * from db where timeColumn >= ?
```

And then I use prepare statement:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setDate(index, new java.sql.Date(((Date) param).getTime()));
```

With Microsoft driver result is incorrect, resultSet contains rows from start of day, ignoring requested hour/minuts etc.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The result is correct: You are using setDate() and a java.sql.Date which only contains year, month and days, not setTimestamp() and a java.sql.Timestamp which also includes a time-part

For example:

new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime())

Answer (score 0):

The answer comes from the javadoc for [java.sql.Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html):

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a
>   java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and
>   milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

In other words, java.sql.Date will have hours, minutes, and seconds fields, but they will always be set to zero.

You should use [java.sql.Timestamp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 
`statement.setTimestamp(index, new java.sql.Timestamp(((Date) param).getTime()));`